# App stops when calling Webview back to Activity Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I developed a simple app that has two activities. When I call Menu activity to Webview using intent, it opens very well in web view, but when I click the button to return back to Activity, it crashes and asks to "close the app." Below is my java and it looks fine without errors. The log cat as well doesn't display any errors.
Who has the solution to these?

public class WebView extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("site_url");
    android.webkit.WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("" + url);


}

private class MywebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.webkit.WebView webView = null;
    if(webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack())
    {
        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: If it crashes, the logcat definitely has an error message and stacktrace. Try again, but don't filter the logcat. Often you can miss important stuff by using the wrong filter.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here, in `onBackPressed()`:

```
android.webkit.WebView webView = null;
if(webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack())
```

You set the variable `webView` to `null` and then you call a method `isFocused()` on it. That will cause a `NullPointerException`.

---

Change this to:

```
android.webkit.WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
if(webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack())
```

Comment: Thanks @ DavidWasser. Please can you kindly re-write me the right code for me to set it right since it is causing a NullPointerException? thanks.